# In Flutter, I can't center cards in containers

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Center(
          child: SelectGroupCard(context, titles: titles, ids: ids,
              onTap: (title, id) {
            setState(() {
              cardGroupResult = title + " " + id;
            });
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

There are several cards as seen in the picture. I want to get these right out. I even want to be able to show these cards in the middle of the page, in 3 columns, 4 rows.

Comment: Can you include more about `SelectGroupCard`?

Answer (score 0):

Use widget `GridView`, it allows you to select the desired number of columns and rows. Also, it is possible to install paddings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GridView

```
GridView(
   gridDelegate:const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
       crossAxisCount:  2, // you can change this
   ),      
   children :[...] // put your cards here !
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the width property of SelectGroupCard. for example, if SelectGroupCard is a row widget, the following code like this:

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [],
)
```